# Why output of array to pointer is not related

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, scope, undefined-behavior

```
int main(){ //main function
MySort sorter;
int* sortedValues;

cout <<  "Random Numbers\n--------------------------\n";
sorter.assignRandom();
sorter.printData();
return 1;
}
```

Here header file:

```
class MySort{
private:
    int* data;
    const int N = 10;


public:
    void assignRandom();
    void printData();
    void printArray(int*);
    int* sortAscending();
    int* sortDescending();
    };
```

its implementation file :

```
void MySort::assignRandom(){ 

    int array[N];
    for(int a=0;a<N;a++){
    array[a] =  (rand() %10)+1; //array fill with random numbers 1 to 10 but output is not  
    }

    data=array;
}

void MySort::printData(){

   for(int a=0;a<N;a++){
    cout<< *(data+a)<<", "; // printing data elements
   }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

Random Numbers:

2, 0, 1905488, 0, 7339472, 0, 1, 0, 50, 0,

Like this but my random number in 1 to 10 where is the problem ?

Comment: `data=array;` turns `data` into a dangling pointer (as `array` goes out of scope after the function ends)

Comment: `int array[N];` is local in function `assignRandom`. You gotta pass this array as input to this function from the outside.

Comment: you could do this a couple of ways, either have your int array in assignRandom rewritten as a private member variable, or you could have array be a dynamic variable allocated to the heap. both would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this member function

```
void MySort::assignRandom(){ 

    int array[N];
    for(int a=0;a<N;a++){
    array[a] =  (rand() %10)+1; //array fill with random numbers 1 to 10 but output is not  
    }

    data=array;
}
```

You are assigning the address of the first element of the local array `array` to the data member `data`.

After exiting the function the local array will not be alive. Its memory can be overwritten. So the pointer `data` is an invalid pointer. As a result the program has undefined behavior.

Either make the array data member of the class or allocate memory dynamically and its address assign to the data member `data`.

Comment: @OğuzhanDuymaz In this case add a constructor that allocates memory dynamically and assigns its address to the data member data and a destructor that will free the allocated memory.